# angularjs - checking whether $scope.$apply is needed

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery project that is slowly migrating to AngularJS. To keep things working , I am introducing AngularJS components one by one, trying to tie them to jQuery handlers using $rootScope as an event bus.

This is how I dispatch events from jQuery:

```
var el = $('[ng-app="cpmsApp"]')[0];
var rootScope = angular.element(el).scope().$root;
rootScope.$emit('someevent', {'value': 'TR'});
```

and this is how I catch them inside the controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('someevent', function(event, passed_obj) {
    console.log('received event');
    console.log(passed_obj);
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.countryfilter = passed_obj.value;
    });
});
```

This works fine while catching events from outside Angular, but when I try to emit an event from within it I get an error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
```

Which, as per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply), means that the explicit `$apply` is not needed.

So my question is, how do I look at the event and check whether to use `$apply` or not? Something along the lines of:

```
if(event.from_within_angular) {
    $scope.countryfilter = passed_obj.value;
} else {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.countryfilter = passed_obj.value;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend doing 
`var rootScope = angular.element(el).scope().$root;` since this will not work with `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`, which is recommended setting [to run AngularJS in production](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production).

As a workaround you can define your broadcast/emit function globally using [`module` run block](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) like:

```
window.rootScopeUtils = {};
angular.module('cpmsApp').run(['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$window', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
    $window.rootScopeUtils.$broadcast = function (event, args) {
        $timeout(function() {  //or $rootScope.$applyAsync(function() {});
            $rootScope.$broadcast(event, args);
        });
    };
}]);
```

And use this function like `window.rootScopeUtils.$broadcast('someevent', {'value': 'TR'})` in your jQuery calls. Since `$broadcast` is wrapped with [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), this will ensure `$digest`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$scope.$apply` the countryfilter will updated each time the event is triggered

```
$rootScope.$on('someevent', function(event, passed_obj) {
    console.log('received event');
    console.log(passed_obj);
    $scope.countryfilter = passed_obj.value;
});
```